# Ruby On Rails Tutorial (Listing 9.43)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am following Ruby on Rails Tutorial by Michael Hartl.I am on chapter 9 Listing 9.43, the problem is that I cannot get the delete link to show and my two tests are failing like so

```
>Failures:
>
> 1) User pages delete links as an admin user 
>     Failure/Error: it { should have_link('delete', href: user_path(User.first)) }
>      expected #has_link?("delete", {:href=>"/users/211"}) to return true, got false
>     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:43:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
>
>  2) User pages delete links as an admin user should be able to delete another user
>     Failure/Error: click_link('delete', match: :first)
>     Capybara::ElementNotFound:
>       Unable to find link "delete"
>     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:46:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'
>     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:45:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
>
>Finished in 12.59 seconds
>73 examples, 2 failures
>
>Failed examples:
>
>rspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:43 # User pages delete links as an admin user 
>rspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:44 # User pages delete links as an admin user >should be able to delete another user
```

Here is my _user.html.eb file

```
<li>
  <%= gravatar_for user, size: 52 %>
  <%= link_to user.name, user %>
  <% if current_user.admin? && !current_user?(user) %>
    | <%= link_to "delete", user, method: :delete,
                                  data: { confirm: "You sure?" } %>
  <% end %>
</li>
```

Here is my factories.rb file

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    sequence(:name)  { |n| "Person #{n}" }
    sequence(:email) { |n| "person_#{n}@example.com"}
    password "foobar"
    password_confirmation "foobar"

    factory :admin do
      admin true
    end
  end
end
```

Here is my sample_data.rake

```
namespace :db do
  desc "Fill database with sample data"
  task populate: :environment do
   admin= User.create!(name: "Example User",
                 email: "example@railstutorial.org",
                 password: "foobar",
                 password_confirmation: "foobar",
                 admin:true)
    99.times do |n|
      name  = Faker::Name.name
      email = "example-#{n+1}@railstutorial.org"
      password  = "password"
      User.create!(name: name,
                   email: email,
                   password: password,
                   password_confirmation: password)
    end
  end
end
```

But I am convinced the problem is here, sessions_helper.rb

```
module SessionsHelper
    def sign_in(user)
        remember_token = User.new_remember_token
        cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = remember_token
        user.update_attribute(:remember_token, User.encrypt(remember_token))
        self.current_user = user
    end
    def signed_in?
        !current_user.nil?
    end

    def current_user=(user)
    @current_user = user
      end

      def current_user?(user)
      user == current_user
    end

    def current_user
        remember_token = User.encrypt(cookies[:remember_token])
        @current_user ||= User.find_by(remember_token: remember_token)
    end
```

Here is my user_pages_specs 
      describe "delete links" do

```
  it { should_not have_link('delete') }

  describe "as an admin user" do
    let(:admin) { FactoryGirl.create(:admin) }
    before do
      sign_in admin
      visit users_path
    end

    it { should have_link('delete', href: user_path(User.first)) }
    it "should be able to delete another user" do
      expect do
        click_link('delete', match: :first)
      end.to change(User, :count).by(-1)
    end
    it { should_not have_link('delete', href: user_path(admin)) }
  end
end
```

Comment: can you show your spec code?

Comment: are you using sample data for specs? you usually use factories, what I mean is that I think your sample data has no relation here, unless you are using it in test database, running task prefixed with `RAILS_ENV=test`

Comment: Found the problem, I missed an end @ the describe links actions...Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that when you check for the `delete link` you are logged in as `admin`.
Also, the following describe block is present in your `spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb` file.

```
describe "delete links" do

  it { should_not have_link('delete') }

  describe "as an admin user" do
    let(:admin) { FactoryGirl.create(:admin) }
    before do
      sign_in admin           ##### Sign in as admin before checking delete link
      visit users_path
    end

    it { should have_link('delete', href: user_path(User.first)) }
    it "should be able to delete another user" do
      expect do
        click_link('delete', match: :first)
      end.to change(User, :count).by(-1)
    end
    it { should_not have_link('delete', href: user_path(admin)) }
  end
end
```

Comment: Found the problem, I missed an end @ the describe links actions...Thanks for help